# How popular are Stack Exchange sites in comparison to each other?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics, analytics

My habitat is ux.stackexchange.com, but sometimes it feels like there are only 10 users that discuss something between them.

I wonder what is the number of daily and monthly active users across each of Stack Exchange sites? Could someone present the data, visualised if possible, please?

Comment: If that's true it probably shouldn't be a separate site. I would think UX issues fit comfortably on stack overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this out... https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

You can see all the sites traffic directly.

Answer (score 4):

**Top 3 sites (Users):**

- Stackoverflow (11m)
- Mathematics (593k)
- Server Fault: (473k)

Source: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic.